# A strange error (undeclared 'ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY') occurred while I compling ffmpeg-3.4.2 on win10(64bit) platform

Tags: ffmpeg

Recently, I try to compile ffmpeg3.4.2 in my pc on win10 (64bit) platform,
some former steps go well, but a error comes out when I run 'make', it says:

> 'ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY' is undeclared in the function 'ff_gai_strerror' of file 'libavformat/os_support.c',

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3M0g.png)

Answer (score 1):

In **win10**, many error code definitions, include `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY`, are written in `winerror.h`.

Add `winerror.h` header in your `os_support.h` will solve the problem.